# LaTeX3 Property lists and expansion

Tags: expansion, expl3

So, I'm trying to pass the "date" value associated with the current environment to a property list defined by a macro. It doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_thedate_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Day}{m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_thedate_tl {#1}
  \begin{center}
    \textbf{#1}
  \end{center}
  Begin:\\
}{
\\
End.
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\writeentry}{mm}{
  \prop_new:c {g_#1_prop}
  \prop_gput:cnn {g_#1_prop} {key} {#1}
  \prop_gput:cnn {g_#1_prop} {value} {#2}
  \prop_gput:cnn {g_#1_prop} {date} {\tl_to_str:N \l_thedate_tl}
  #1 \hspace{2em} #2
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getdate}{m}{
  \prop_get:cn {g_#1_prop} {date}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getvalue}{m}{
  \prop_get:cn {g_#1_prop}{value}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{Day}{14 April}
  \writeentry{foo}{Something}

  \writeentry{bar}{Something else}
\end{Day}

Get Value: \getvalue{foo} \hspace{2em}
Get Date: \getdate{foo}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the `\getdate` function doesn't print anything. But as I understand it, it should print the value that `\l_thedate_tl` had when the property list was set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are storing the literal tokens `\tl_to_str:N \l_thedate_tl}` in the `prop`, and at point-of-use `\l_thedate_tl` is empty: is that what you are missing?

Comment: Probably you want `\prop_gput:cnV {g_#1_prop} {date} \l_thedate_tl`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want `\tl_to_str:N` and most of all you don't want to put `\tl_to_str:N \l_thedate_tl` into the property list, but the value of the token list variable. So `\prop_gput:cnV` is your friend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_seamus_thedate_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Day}{m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_seamus_thedate_tl {#1}
  \begin{center}
    \textbf{#1}
  \end{center}
  Begin:\\
}{
\\
End.
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\writeentry}{mm}{
  \prop_new:c {g_seamus_#1_prop}
  \prop_gput:cnn {g_seamus_#1_prop} {key} {#1}
  \prop_gput:cnn {g_seamus_#1_prop} {value} {#2}
  \prop_gput:cnV {g_seamus_#1_prop} {date} \l_seamus_thedate_tl
  #1 \hspace{2em} #2
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getdate}{m}{
  \prop_get:cn {g_seamus_#1_prop} {date}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getvalue}{m}{
  \prop_get:cn {g_seamus_#1_prop}{value}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{Day}{14 April}
  \writeentry{foo}{Something}

  \writeentry{bar}{Something else}
\end{Day}

Get Value: \getvalue{foo} \hspace{2em}
Get Date: \getdate{foo}
\end{document}
```

If I also ask `\prop_show:N \g_seamus_foo_prop` I get

```
The property list \g_seamus_foo_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {key}  =>  {foo}
>  {value}  =>  {Something}
>  {date}  =>  {14 April}.
```

which seems exactly what you want.

Note the use of a prefix, which is heartily recommended.

---

### A crash course on variants

The main function you're using is `\prop_gput:Nnn`, but nowhere you type it, but rather a couple of variants thereof.

The kernel has a definition for `\prop_gput:Nnn` and then it says

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cnn }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { NnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cnV }
```

(and some other variants). These commands really define three new functions

```
\prop_gput:cnn
\prop_gput:NnV
\prop_gput:cnV
```

that are based on the main function, preceded by some `\expandafter` trickery so that calling

```
\prop_gput:cnn { g_seamus_foo_prop } { X } { Y }
```

is equivalent to calling

```
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_seamus_foo_prop { X } { Y }
```

that is, a control sequence name is formed from the argument. Of course this is useful only when the control sequence name has a variable part, as in your code.

Calling

```
\prop_gput:NnV \g_seamus_foo_prop { X } \l_seamus_thedate_tl
```

is instead equivalent to calling

```
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_seamus_foo_prop { X } { <value of \l_seamus_thedate_tl> }
```

So a `V` argument is substituted with the variable's value *in braces*. The third function is just a combination of the two variants above.

This provides a unified way of doing things, without multiplying the “base names” of functions: all of them are `\prop_gput:<signature>`.

Comment: Thanks. So the `V` expands the argument? Is that the right way to think about it?

Comment: @Seamus `V` presents the argument to the function as if it were the variable's value enclosed in braces.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. I am slowly getting the hang of the LaTeX3 way!